# How to Display JSON Parsed Data in Popup Using jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, json

I am using image map and i want to display data in popup when i click any coords then data display in popup. How to show data in popup if i write code in jQuery?
Below, is my HTML, jQuery and C# Code. The Data is fetched frpm the database and should be displayed in popup. C# code and jQuery code working fine but, how to display data in popup?

**HTML**

```
        <img src="~/image/map.jpg" usemap="#image-map" class="map" />

        <map name="image-map" class="map">
            <area target="" alt="" title="" href="" id="2" coords="1008,370,33" shape="circle">
            <area target="" alt="" title="" href="" coords="962,420,23" shape="circle">
            <area target="" alt="" title="" href="" coords="932,461,18" shape="circle">
            <area target="" alt="" title="" href="" coords="888,464,867,485,907,541,929,501" shape="poly">
            <area target="" alt="" title="" href="" coords="851,507,836,532,876,566,907,541" shape="poly">
        </map>

        <label id="mname"></label>
        <label id="city"></label>
        <label id="mid"></label>
        <label id="cordsid"></label>


    </form>
```

**Script**

```
<script>

        $(".map area").click(function () {

            $.ajax({
                url:'@Url.Action("Member_Detail")',
                data: { 'cords': this.id },
                type: "post",
                cache: false,
                dataType: "JSONP",
                success: function (resdata) {
                    alert("success", resdata);
                },
                error: function (result, status, err) {
                    console.log("error", result.responseText);
                    console.log("error", status.responseText);
                    console.log("error", err.Message);
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

**C#**

```
public JsonResult Member_Detail(int cords)
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test"].ConnectionString;

            MemberDetail m_Detail = new MemberDetail();
            using (SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Employee where EmployeeID='" + cords+"'", con);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

                con.Open();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    m_Detail.EmployeeID = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["EmployeeID"]);
                    m_Detail.Name = dt.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString();
                    m_Detail.Position = dt.Rows[i]["Position"].ToString();
                    m_Detail.Address = dt.Rows[i]["Address"].ToString();
                    m_Detail.Salary = dt.Rows[i]["Salary"].ToString();
                    m_Detail.Office = dt.Rows[i]["Office"].ToString();

                }
            }
            return Json(m_Detail, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: use Modal from bootstrap   https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/

Comment: How to write in jquery code and where .

Comment: you need first of all the html code and then in your ajax success the jquery code from bootstrap. You must to link also bootstrap(.js  and. css) in your project

Comment: And how to give column name

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cristiannn/pb2wtaus/9/ here is an example  (it shhould to look like this https://jsfiddle.net/cristiannn/pb2wtaus/11/)

Comment: Sir i understand this i just want to understand How to display EmployeeID, Name,Position  i need syntax .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Using jQuery UI

**CSS:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```

**jQuery and jQuery UI scripts:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

**On your script:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".map area").on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url:'@Url.Action("Member_Detail")',
                data: { 'cords': this.id },
                type: "post",
                cache: false,
                dataType: "JSONP",
                success: function (resdata) {
                    var dataResult = JSON.parse(resdata);
                    $("#popup").append('<p>' + "" /* print dataResult here */ + '</p>');
                    $("#popup").dialog();
                },
                error: function (result, status, err) {
                    console.log("error", result.responseText);
                    console.log("error", status.responseText);
                    console.log("error", err.Message);
                }
            });
        });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="popup" title="MyPopup">
<p>sample_content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: if i want to show EmployeeID so i will write this code $("#popup").append('<p>' + ""  dataResult.EmployeeID + '</p>');

Comment: try: $("#popup").append('<p>' + dataResult.EmployeeID + '</p>');
if not work:
try: $("#popup").append('<p>' + dataResult['EmployeeID'] + '</p>');

Comment: if not work: iterate through dataResult ...

if not work: try console.log(dataResult) ... from here the console (press F12) will show you how to display the data

Comment: Sir Popup not display and Not showing any error when i debug using break point.

Comment: i see your code is working my jquery is not working , i don't know whats a problem not showing any error .

Comment: when i use button then popup display but when i use img and add click event popup not display .

Comment: i already check put variable in console but nothing to show anything .

Comment: How to send you whole script ?

Comment: i have past whole script of application just image is not share if you want to image i can share also image.

Comment: made changes to my answer: look at the new **click handler** ... also added `e.preventDefault();`